# Unexpected layout behavior in JavaFX

Tags: layout, javafx, resize, containers, region

I want to write a new custom container class extending Region. The children list of this CustomContainer should not be visible. It contains a Pane (called rootPane) which in turn contains a VBox. And the children list of this VBox should be used to really add children to the container (accessible through getInnerChildren). That is the simplified structure of it.

My problem is that adding a new child causes a wrong layout behavior of the CustomContainer itself in case a border is applied to it because it grows in its height. But only the first time a child is added! Here is a really simple executable Demo to test it:

```
public class LayoutDemo extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        CustomContainer container = new CustomContainer(new Label("First Label"), new Label("Second Label"), new Label("Third Label"));
        // The border here is involved in the problem. In fact, only the top width has influence.
        container.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.GRAY, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, new BorderWidths(30, 3, 3, 3))));

        Button buttonAddNode = new Button("Add node");
        buttonAddNode.setOnAction(e -> container.specialAction());
        Button buttonSysout = new Button("Sysout height");
        buttonSysout.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println(container.getHeight()));

        HBox boxButtons = new HBox(10, buttonAddNode, buttonSysout);
        VBox sceneRoot = new VBox(20, container, boxButtons);
        sceneRoot.setPadding(new Insets(15)); // Just to make it look nicer.
        stage.setScene(new Scene(sceneRoot, 200, 200));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class CustomContainer extends Region
    {
        private VBox innerBox = new VBox();
        private Pane rootPane = new StackPane(innerBox);

        public CustomContainer(Node... children)
        {
            getChildren().addAll(rootPane);
            getInnerChildren().addAll(children);
        }

        public void specialAction()
        {
            // Just for testing... Forces the CustomContainer to add a child to itself. And this is where the trouble begins...
            Node newChild = new Pane();
            newChild.setManaged(false); // I tried this, but it really has no influence.

            // The new child won't be visible in this test because it is not considered by layoutChildren(). But even layouting it would have no influence.
            getChildren().add(newChild);
        }

        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren()
        {
            System.out.println("LAYOUT");
            Insets borderInsets = getBorder().getInsets();
            double left = borderInsets.getLeft(),
                top = borderInsets.getTop(),
                width = getWidth() - left - borderInsets.getRight(),
                height = getHeight() - top - borderInsets.getBottom();
            layoutInArea(rootPane, left, top, width, height, 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
        }

        public ObservableList<Node> getInnerChildren()
        {
            return innerBox.getChildren();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**Further hints:**
- The size it grows in its height is equal to the top width of the border.
- If you replace the VBox with a HBox the left width of the border is decisive instead.
- It has to do with my overridden layoutChildren() method. If not overridden the problem not appears (but of course I need to implement this method, just correctly).
- As mentioned it only appears the first time a child is added. But removing it does not revert the size.
- The "specialAction" method represents some logic that is done internally. That is because I want to internally add and remove some new children to the CustomContainer (and not to the VBox!) but the problem appears the same way when adding children to the VBox.

In case you are curious what I plan with this container: It will implement some drag and drop behaviour to move children around with some custom visual feedback. And this visual feedback will be installed on the non public children list of the CustomContainer.
Please do not suggest to alter the container structure. Instead I hope you can give me advice why my layoutChildren method causes this problem and how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set minimum width and height to your nodes. I have quite similar behavior as yours and I come across this article https://dzone.com/articles/size-does-matter-in-javafx, then I set minimum height to my AnchorPane and the unexpected behavior is gone.

Comment: No. But the solution was to override the compute methods as well.